# Comparing capture efficiencies of sampling gear?

Tags: population, ecology

I have capture data for a fisheries population assessment. Two different crews were used that did surveys separately, each with variations in specifications of the gear that they used (same gear type/different models).

I'm wondering how I can compare if there were different capture efficiencies between the two gear types. I have length/weight data for all fish caught. The only issue is that the number of sites surveyed by Crew 1 and 2 were not the same. Crew #2 only helped a fraction of the time.

My guess is to plot the length/weight distributions of the fish caught by Crew #2 from the X sample sites they surveyed. Then, because Crew #1 surveyed more sites, randomly select the same number of sites that Crew #2 sampled, and plot the length/weight distributions from those X sites.

This gets further complicated by the fact that any differences seen in the distributions  might be due to a variety of variables such as habitat type present at each site, time of day etc. This is not the main question of the project. I'm just wondering how I can give my best effort at looking into this possible relationship before explaining my other results that show the sites that Crew #2 sample result in overestimations of the fish community.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need to balance the number of sites. I imagine you could use regression to test whether capture efficiency differs between gear.

However, what exactly do you mean by "capture efficiency"? How does that relate to the length/weight of the fish? I'm assuming that a higher length/weight of fish per site would translate to higher capture efficiency? It's important to define this clearly as this will be the "response" in your regression model.

So your data would look something like this:

```
Gear   Length/Weight   Site
gear_a            10      A
gear_a            12      B
gear_a            15      C
gear_b             9      D
gear_b            11      E
```

And you would then have a regression model where Length/weight (or whatever you decide is your measure of capture efficiency) is the response (or dependent variable) and Gear is the predictor (or independent variable).

A few things to consider:

What form does your response take - if it is a count or a proportion you may want to use a generalized linear model.

Do the different crews ever visit the same sites? If they do, you may want to include Site as a random variable in the model.

By the sounds of it, it's very likely that you have unmeasured variables and co-variables that may also affect your response. e.g. the different gear is also manned by different crews on different boats. They may have fished at different times of day or during different conditions, or in different habitats. You will therefore have to be careful how you interpret your results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Capture efficiency is basically how well each crew catches fish in relation to each other. The reason length/weight is important is because the gear specifications of one crew might result in catching more fish of a certain size. There are a lot of variables at play here so it will be difficult to make any concrete conclusions, but I will try exploring some regressions. Again, this is more of just a side question, so it's not extremely important, but should be explored to the extent that we can given the data we have. Thanks again!